# why my webview displays differently this link than my browser

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm tring to load this url in a WebView :

> https://crocodoc.com/view/PFk2xRsJYPjfDhhm-2nfzi1CnZtUvvXqpy7Uh7uCcFGTfiFDbVpzbgJ2kSUyGGRkf1M_eq_COHKAf14Okz0ShL0WzoNiprqf2UWXUSP7hJ0CHiCGaP4Vs7CHKJAW2A

I tried the basic way :

```
wv.loadUrl("..");
```

within an Iframe :

```
String str2 = "<body style=\"margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden\">\n" +
                   "<iframe src=\""+"https://crocodoc.com/view/"+sessionId+"\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>\n" +
              "</body>";    
wv.loadData(str2, "text/html","utf-8");
```

With a classic client, a chrome chient, enabling more of less every WebView Setting that I could think of. But I loose the controls, I just see an horribele zommed view of the document, I can't zoom etc...

I only left :

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

In my phone browsers It displays as I want it to.

So my question is : why ? how should I do to make it look the same way than in firefox or chrome.

Thanks